# Android camera2 - Flash turns off before taking the picture

Tags: android, android-camera2

I do following:

```
CaptureRequest captureRequest;

captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

captureRequest = captureRequestBuilder.build();

cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest, captureCallBackListener, backgroundHandler);
```

...but the flash turns off before the picture was taken.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help:

> CONTROL_AE_MODE
>   added in API level 21
>   public static final Key CONTROL_AE_MODE
>   The desired mode for the camera device's auto-exposure routine.
>   This control is only effective if android.control.mode is AUTO.
>   When set to any of the ON modes, the camera device's auto-exposure routine is enabled, overriding the application's selected exposure time, sensor sensitivity, and frame duration (android.sensor.exposureTime, android.sensor.sensitivity, and android.sensor.frameDuration). If one of the FLASH modes is selected, the camera device's flash unit controls are also overridden.
>   The FLASH modes are only available if the camera device has a flash unit (android.flash.info.available is true).
>   If flash TORCH mode is desired, this field must be set to ON or OFF, and android.flash.mode set to TORCH.
>   When set to any of the ON modes, the values chosen by the camera device auto-exposure routine for the overridden fields for a given capture will be available in its CaptureResult.

this is from here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest